# How to get an OData Web Api 2.2 Controller to return a complex type from a function?

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a self hosted Web API that uses OData 4 controllers. I'm trying to create a function that will return an Object.

```
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder.EntitySet<User>(typeof (User).Name);
        builder.EntitySet<UserGroup>(typeof (UserGroup).Name);
        builder.EntitySet<SystemAccount>(typeof (SystemAccount).Name);

        builder.Namespace = "UserService";
        builder.EntityType<User>().Action("GetPermissions").Returns<PermissionContainer>();

        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", null, builder.GetEdmModel());
        config.AddODataQueryFilter();
```

This is my controller's method

```
    // GET: /User(5)/GetPermissions
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPermissions(int key)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Ok(_userService.GetPermissionsByUserId(key));
    }
```

When I run this app I get the following

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Web.OData.dll
>
> Additional information: The type 'Model.User' cannot be configured
>   as a ComplexType. It was previously configured as an EntityType.

What I want to do is to use the URL "/User(101)/GetPermissions" to return an object type PermissionContainer.

Also, PermissionContainer is NOT an entity. It is a Class that I created which has numerious bool values that indicates user permissions based on the entity type Users and UserGroups.

Comment: perhaps this code sample can help you out.
https://gist.github.com/bradwilson/8586562